# app:cornerRadius is not working in android material design button

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme, material-components-android, material-components

How to change corner radius of android material button. I tried setting corner radius but its not working.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="Start"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:cornerRadius="8dp" />
```

[image: see the image attached]

Comment: Check your app theme. To use the Material Components library you have to use a [Material Components Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to set the `style` of Button like below

and to use Material Design you need to add below `dependencies` in `gradle`.

```
dependencies { implementation ‘com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0’ }
```

XML

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
   app:cornerRadius="8dp"/>
```

Comment: It is not correct.  `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` is the default style applied by the Material Components theme. If you need to add it, may ne you are using the wrong theme in your app.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use 'background' attribute — this is forbidden technique. Use 'backgroundTint' instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it means that you **are not using** a theme that inherits from a [**Material Components theme**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme).
It is the attribute in the material compoments theme which defines the default style used by a `MaterialButton`:

```
<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
```

**Only in this case** you will have to specify the text field style as well, via `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"`:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
   ..>
```

Final note: starting from `1.1.0` you have to use a Material Components Theme or a Bridge Theme.

Comment: This is correct answer! You should apply material them to your app first.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried many ways, but the best way can resolve my problem is:
change `android:background` to `android:backgroundTint`.